# Xcode Admob singleton - "use of undeclared identifier "shared"" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, singleton, admob

Okay first post ever on any forum but i'll do my best to describe my problem. I'm a beginner at Xcode so i'm sorta expecting an easy solution, but i just can't seem to figure this one out.

In Xcode i am trying to create an Admob singleton to get admob in all my view controllers. Admob will back up iAd, which will be showed should Ad fail.

I followed this guide: http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.dk/2012/04/creating-gadbannerview-singleton-in.html

I created a GADMasterViewController .m and .h file

The GADMasterViewController.h looks like this

```
#import "GADBannerView.h"

@interface GADMasterViewController : UIViewController <GADBannerViewDelegate> {
    GADBannerView *adbanner_;
    BOOL isLoaded_;
    id currentDelegate_;
}



@end
```

and the GADMasterViewController.m file looks exactly as the one in the guide except i put #import "GADMasterViewController.h" at the top.

Then in my viewController.m where i want the ad to show i put

```
- (void)bannerView:(GADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
    _UIiAd.hidden = YES;

    shared = [GADMasterViewController singleton];
    [shared resetAdview:self]
}
```

However in viewController.m i get the following errors:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63928888/Sk%C3%A6rmbillede%202014-09-15%20kl.%2000.17.02.png

Basically it doesn't recognize the returned "shared" err singleton (or whatever "shared" is) from GADMasterViewController.m

How do i "get" "shared" so my viewController doesn't produce these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `shared`, but you haven't defined it as a variable (local or otherwise).

So, change

```
shared = [GADMasterViewController singleton];
[shared resetAdview:self]
```

to either

```
GADMasterViewController  *shared = [GADMasterViewController singleton];
[shared resetAdview:self];
```

or

```
[[GADMasterViewController singleton] resetAdview:self];
```

so that you are defining the variable, or so that you don't need a variable.

Comment: Checking the error again, you also need to `#import GADMasterViewController.h`

Comment: Now i get these errors:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63928888/Sk%C3%A6rmbillede%202014-09-15%20kl.%2001.15.19.png

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63928888/Sk%C3%A6rmbillede%202014-09-15%20kl.%2001.15.30.png

Then again i haven't declared "shared" in GADMasterViewController.h, should i do this? if yes, how?

Comment: Your problem is no longer with `shared`, it is with your GADMasterViewController.h file because it doesn't define the methods you're trying to use. It seems that you don't understand the basic principles of class definition and relationships and you should go and read about that https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW1

Comment: Okay I'll do that, thank you very much for your help

Comment: Hey just wanted to let you know i figured it out. Not really because of the article you linked to, but reading that article made me understand some basics about the objective c language. I found the solution (in another form) here on stack overflow, because the knowledge from the link you sent helped me understand what to look/search for. Also, looking at the article you linked again, the solution is actually written there, i just didn't get it at first, because it only described how to define the methods, but not where to define them. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: Cool. Please accept answers that solved your problem or up vote if they helped. p.s. welcome to SO ;-)

Comment: @Chikara I'm having the same problem with admob singleton. Can you explain your solution because I can't seem to get it.

Comment: @user2995344 It's quite some time since i fixed this, however as I recall it, I forgot to declare the methods that I was trying to access. These should be declared in the h file of your admob class. In my case it was " + (nameOfYourClass *)singleton; " or " + (GADMasterViewController *)singleton; " if you followed the guide I followed. The other method that must be declared is " -(void)resetAdView:(UIViewController *)rootViewController; "
Again this is following the guide. Declare these, and you should be able to access "shared". Remember to import the GADMasterViewController.h in your class